# I want to iterate trough a txt in python and change each word

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a stucture called `dictionary` and it looks like this:

```
dictionary = {"The" : "A", "sun": "nap", "shining" : "süt", 
                 "wind": "szél", "not" : "nem", "blowing" : "fúj"}
```

I want to iterate trough a .txt and change each word to its key pair and push it to a new txt.

My idea was something like this but it's just returning values:

```
dict = {"The" : "A", "sun": "nap", "shining" : "süt", "wind" : "szél", "not" : "nem", "blowing" : "fúj"}
def translate(string, dict):
    for key in dict:
        string = string.replace(key, dict[key]())
    return string()
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample output please?

Comment: Well, if you want to "iterate through each word", then first you need to get words from the file, yes? Do you know how to split up a string into the individual words?

Comment: Could you post some sample input/ouput

Comment: Also, please show *actual code* that you tried, not "something like" your idea. I assume you were able to read the file, for example, since you got *some* kind of output. And I'm sure you didn't actually write `return string()`, because the string isn't callable.

Comment: why are you written this `dict[key]()`. Many syntax errors in your program.

Comment: Example input in a txt file: The sun is shining. The wind is not blowing.

Comment: Example output in a txt file: A nap süt. A szél nem fúj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very naive approach is to read each line in the file and replace using your dictionary

```py
d = {'old': 'new'}
new_lines = []
with open('a.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        for key, value in d.items():
            new_lines.append(line.replace(key, value))

with open('b.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(new_lines)
```

**Note:-** This would convert line `old is gold` to `new is gnew`. Hence you may want to break the line further into words and then match the whole word for replacing and save accordingly

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful! I have another question! 
If there is a word in the a.txt that is not in the dictionary, how can i not include that (like delete it) from b.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Use `re` to avoid overlapping replacement. The pattern is built from the escaped keys and the replacement string is dynamically mapped using a lambda expression.

```
import re

table = {"The": "A", "sun": "nap", "shining": "süt", "wind": "szél", "not": "nem", "blowing": "fúj"}


def translate(string, mapping):
    pattern = r'(' + r'|'.join(re.escape(k) for k in mapping.keys()) + r')'
    return re.sub(pattern, lambda m: mapping[m.group(1)], string)


print(translate('The sun is not blowing wizd', table))
```